# Removing XML tags when parsing XML

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Using Ruby with Nokogiri is there an easy way to remove tags around returned results? I can't find one in the docs.

Example from the [Nokogiri site](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html):

```
characters[0].to_s # => "<character>Al Bundy</character>"
```

I was hoping to get:

```
Al Bundy
```

Comment: Can you post the XML that you're trying to parse?

Comment: You don't understand how Nokogiri works. When we locate a tag, we get a XML::Node or HTML::Node. A node consists of the tag, all of its parameters and any child nodes embedded inside it. If you do `characters[0]` you're slicing a NodeSet, which is like an array of nodes, looking at the first node, and `to_s` simply turns the tag and contents into a string. I'd recommend reading through the [XML::Node](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node) documentation as it covers everything you'd want to do with a node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [`text` method](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#text-instance_method):

```
characters[0].text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .inner_html method. Here is an example you can use from a basic xml sitemap:

```
parse_content.css("url").each do |x|
  location = x.css("loc").inner_html
  last_mod = x.css("lastmod").inner_html
end
```

You can read about sitemaps here: https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html